# Автоматическое скругление углов в зависимости от ее высоты iOS

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uibutton

Можно ли в строчке коде в `override func viewDidLoad() {}` прописать автоматическое скругление углов кнопки?

Условно:

```
convert.layer.cornerRadius = heigth / 2
convert.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

Хочу сделать так, что бы в зависимости от высоты кнопки или ее ширины он скруглял углы, деля ее пополам, что бы получить круг.

Comment: Для этого лучше создать кастомный класс для кнопки, і в етом классе в методе layoutSubviews применить скругление.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно тебя понял, то

```
let height = convert.bounds.size.height
convert.layer.cornerRadius = heigth / 2
convert.layer.masksToBounds = true
```